# Query that accesses 2 feilds of document in collection

Tags: mongodb, subquery, aggregate, node.js

I have a users collection of documents containing fields **city_name**, and **income**. How can I write a query which gives me the documents data of the top 10 cities which have the highest number of users and their average income?

I tried this but it's not working.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$city",
      no_of_users: { $sum: 1 },
      avg_income: { $avg: { $convert: { input: "$income", to: "double" } } }
    }
  }
])
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.